# No output in Webview when using embed tag with video file as source

Tags: android, html, webview

I written an app for android 2.2 device and I am using android webview in my app. In html file i have below line of code, but the video is not playing.

```
<embed width="320" height="240" controls="console" src="videos/xylo.mp4" hidden="false" autostart="true"/>
```

Is there any permissions required to add in manifest file.

Please help me regarding this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
<embed width="320" height="240" controls="console" src="videos/xylo.mp4"  autostart="true"/>
```

You just need to remove  (hidden ="false") attribute

Comment: Please check your path of Video. I hope your src is not correct.
Please use url instead of static path

Comment: If you are using php on this html page then use dirname( _ _ FILE _ _ ).'/videos/xylo.mp4' like this.

Comment: i am keeping html and video files in assets folder